# Charge distribution in a conducting rod moving through a magnetic filed

Tags: electromagnetism, integration

If a conducting rod of length l is moving through a homogenous magnetic field B, we get that the resulting electric field in the rod is given by:

$$ E = v \times B  $$

(if we assume constant velocity and neglect self-inducting phenomena) Now we can consider a specific point x along the rod. The infinitesimal contributions to the electric field at that point due to the other parts of the rod should be:

$$\mathrm dE = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\mu(s)}{(s-x)^2}\mathrm ds $$

where $\mu(s)$ is the charge density at point s along the rod. Integrating this along the length of the rod:

$$ E = \int_0^l \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\mu(s)}{(s-x)^2}\mathrm ds $$

which is a Fredholm Equation of the First Kind which I was unable to solve. I noticed that $\mu(s)$ should be symmetric with opposite signs about l/2. I also tried integrating in the domain of x, resulting in:

$$ \Delta U = Ex = \int_0^l \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\mu(s)}{s-x}\mathrm ds $$

Which seems easier to solve, but I still lack the mathematical skillset to effectively solve the problem. Is there a way to get to $\mu(s)$, maybe with a different approach?